# WMI Query extremely slow

Tags: windows, wmi

I'm trying to run a query that gets the windows service name corresponding to a process ID:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_Service where ProcessId = {myID}
```

This query is expected to run for valid or invalid process IDs as my component may run on a windows service, or as part of the main application or even tests.

When I use `run > wbemtest` and test this query with a non existing pid it usually comes back instantly, but there's one machine where this takes 2 minutes.

I don't understand why this runs so much slower on that machine particularly, is there a way to diagnose what's causing this? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For investigating WMI issues, there are different places in the event viewer:

- Windows Logs, Application and System
- Application and Services Logs

  - Microsoft

    - Windows
    - WMI-Activity (in the View menu, you might need to switch on "Show Analytic and Debug logs)

A lot is described in [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmi-troubleshooting).

Comment: While this gives a bit of information, in the end, a windows update happened the next day and the issue got fixed when the pc was restarted.